# Classify math problem

Tags: ratio

Hoping someone can help with following 2 points on question detailed below:

1) Help to clarify what kind of question this is (e.g. ratio problem) so I could plug into google and get meaningful insight. Had to supply a 'tag' to post this question so guessed with 'ratio'.

2) Help solve specific example below.

### Set-up Question (version that I know how to do)

Lets say I own a business that provides 3 services, and expect employees to be able to do x per hour based on below.
1) Walk dogs -> expected rate is 1 per hour
2) Wash cars -> expected rate is 1 per hour
3) Clean houses -> expected rate is 1 per hour

Now lets say I have an employee that works 40hrs per week and he walked 10 dogs, washed 15 cars, and cleaned 5 houses.
His production against a goal of 100% would be 10(dogs)+15(cars)+5(houses)/40(hr work week) = 75%. So basically, he only reached 75% of the goal for that week.

### Real Question (that I need help with)

The exact question from above, except now the expected rates per job type are different:
1) Walk dogs -> expected rate is 3 per hour
2) Wash cars -> expected rate is 2 per hour
3) Clean houses -> expected rate is 1 per hour

I appreciate any help in understanding 'what' kind of problem this is and how to solve!

Comment: The total "ratio" measuring the productivity is "number of hour worked"/40 hours.

Comment: Thus, in the second case, to walk 10 dogs with a "unit productivity" of 3 dogs per hour, he needs $\dfrac {10}{3}=3,33$ hours.

Comment: The same for cars: $\dfrac {15}{2}=7,5$ hours.

Comment: Conclusion: the total number of hours worked are: $3,33+7,5+5=15,33$ hours.

Comment: Google ["working together" math problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22working+together%22+math+problem)

Comment: It is only a problem of *algebra*: we have a "speed" (dogs per hour) and a "space" (dogs); thus computing space/speed we get "time".

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Mauro ALLEGRANZA and Dave L. Renfro in comments. Exactly what I needed and the problem/solution is now clear. Thanks guys!